# send form data using ajax to another page

Tags: jquery, multipartform-data

i am making a image upload system in which when i select file i want to send that data of the form to another page so that i can work on the other functions required . I tried `Serialize` but id didnt worked i am trying `FormData` now but it does not works too.  My code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("form#cropimage").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each($(this)[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'modules/uploader/ajax_image.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
    });
    });
```

html

```
<form id="cropimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image_name" id="image_name" value="<?php echo $actual_image_name ;?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

also i am little confused about how to get this data on the other page normally we use `$_REQUEST` but what to do in this case . As there is a error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` i cant seem to alert anything too .

Comment: use an image upload plugin....lots of them to choose from and they provide cross browser support

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the suggestion . I was using plugins and i really want to make my own code and learn more . If possible could you suggest where i am wrong in this code

Comment: would have to convert image to base64...but can't do that in all browsers. If really want to understand....go through source of a plugin and look at various methods used